# All IBOutlets in a view controller are nil

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, iboutlet

All IBOutlets are nil in my View Controller. I don't know why it is happening

I get the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I have used this code to set the variable finalScore from another controller:

```
let resultController = ResultsViewController()

resultController.finalScore = score
          
navigationController?.pushViewController(ResultsViewController, animated: true)
```

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    var finalScore = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if finalScore <= 2 {
            titleLabel.text = "Better Luck Next Time..."
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "fail")
        } else {
            titleLabel.text = "Nice!!"
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pass")
        }
        
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(finalScore)"
        
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on this line:
[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdUMH.png)

It even shows the outlets are nil here:
[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwURn.png)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you deleted the outlets manually in code at some point during development and then added them afterwards again?

Comment: I have one tried to delete the view controller from storyboard and delete the code from ResultsViewController class and then did all over again. It didn't help.

Comment: How do you navigate to `ResultsViewController`?

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are creating and displaying your `ResultsViewController`.

Comment: If you have code that creates a ResultsViewController with `ResultsViewController()` anywhere, that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have used this kind of code. I have edited the question regarding it, if it is causing the problem, How do I fix it?

Comment: `ResultsViewController()` creates a brand new instance, it's not the instance in the storyboard so the outlets are not connected. You need a segue or to instantiate the controller from the storyboard. See http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

You should open your Storyboard, select the ViewControler, go to the left pane and get to the Connections Inspector. There you should see a warning for the Outlets. You should remove the Outlet here by clicking on the little x next to it. Delete the Outlets also in code and then add them again.[image]

So the problem is, that you cannot just delete Outlets or Actions in code. You have to remove them also in the Connections Inspector.

Comment: I do not find any warnings here, it seems to be fine
I even tried removing and adding again but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your Outlets are nil? Could you show the line, where the error occured?

Comment: I have edited the question showing the images of the error

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and fixed it. The problem was in the other ViewController, I created an instance of the ResultsViewCotnroller class. I removed it and replaced it with:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let customViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomViewController") as!CustomViewController
```

vadian's comment helped me to do so

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing checkmark in FileInspector -> Target Membership.